# Should I run pytest in the Dockerfile in CI?

Tags: continuous-integration, pytest

I want to have a CI process for python application that basically does the following:

- Run pytest to check that the application is working properly

- If pytest succeed - package the application as a Docker image and push it to registry

I am doubting about how to do this. On the one hand, this approach:

```
# requirements.txt
numpy
some-other-dependecncy
...

# Dockerfile
RUN pip install -r requirements
COPY application .

CMD ["python3", "application"]

# CI pipeline

// in python base image 
1. pip install -r  requirements.txt (requirements doesn't contain pytest)
2. pip install pytest
3. pytest
// on host
4. docker build
5. docker push
```

is better since I don't want pytest in my final image. The downside is that I run pip install twice.

The other approach is:

```
# requirements.txt
numpy
...
pytest

# Dockerfile
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY application .
RUN pytest

CMD ["python3", "application"]

# CI pipeline
1. docker build
2. docker push
```

This is more time effective, as I only run pip install once, but leaves my image with pytest, which is unnecessary.

Which is preferred?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an image with pytest to run your tests so you don't need to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting here in case it helps others.

You can add a separate step in your build CI pipeline that uses the `docker exec` command. This allows you to access your container through a bash shell. Make sure you named your container (because you'll need to know what container to access).

So after you've built your image, you can do:

`docker run -it *more args* --name=my_container my_image:latest`

and then, depending on your setup (poetry, pip, ...):

`docker exec my_container_container python -m pytest`

This should return the status code of pytest, which you can use to have your pipeline proceed or fail.

The advantage here is that you don't have to worry about the Dockerfile or entry points, as long as you have pytest in the container with your project.